# How can I safely get the version of ksh?

Tags: shell-script, ksh, version, portability

How can I *safely* get the version of ksh from within a ksh script?

I have [seen the following solutions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-appleosx-get-ksh-version-check-ksh-version/):

1. `ksh --version`
2. `echo ${.sh.version}`
3. `echo $KSH_VERSION`

And given the right circumstances, each of these works correctly.  However, I care about the non-perfect case.

Specifically, there are several machines I work with that have older versions of ksh that, for my purposes, are severely lacking in functionality.  Anyway, the reason I want to check the version (programmatically) is to see if the ksh version is one of the less capable versions; and if so, I want to execute a branch with less awesome code.

However, on the problematic machines, the shell's ineptitude extends into checking the version...

- If I try `ksh --version`, it prints nothing and opens a new instance of `ksh`!
- If I try `echo ${.sh.version}`, `ksh` treats this as a syntax error that cannot be discarded with `2> /dev/null`.

  ```
  $ echo ${.sh.version} 2> /dev/null  
  ksh: ${.sh.version}: bad substitution
  ```
- Of course `echo $KSH_VERSION` appears to work fine – I mean it won't crash – though on these machines it's blank.  Also, I saw [somewhere](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/7654-korn-shell-version-runtime.html) that `KSH_VERSION` is set only by `pdksh`.

Questions:

- How can I safely check the version of `ksh` programmatically?  For my purposes here, I don't really care what the actual version number is, just whether it's an outdated version of `ksh`.
- Is `$KSH_VERSION` good enough?  I mean if it's blank, then is `ksh` necessarily an outdated version? Was that other forum correct that it might not be set even for newer versions of `ksh`?
- Is there just no way to check this at all?

Comment: Any reason you want two code paths and not just a single one with less awesome code?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen it has to do with the prompt.  In my .kshrc file, I have a function that simulates the pwd-abbreviating functionality of tcsh and zsh prompts, and I set up `PS1` to use this function.  However, Old ksh does not support `$()` in `PS1`.  So if it's a modern version of ksh, I want `PS1` to use the function I created; if it's the old version, I use just `$PWD`.

Comment: Well, you _could_ have two versions of your configuration file (perhaps one generated from the other) and then distribute out the appropriate version to the machine in question?

Comment: Another approach could be to simply say "It is only this particular machine which has the problem - I'll find a file or environment variable or something else which only exists here (probably AIX or something anyway) and test for that instead".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I was writing a script for `ksh`, I noticed that the `-a` option of ksh's built-in `whence` command appears to not be supported in older versions of `ksh`. And this appears to be true on all the systems I checked, which included Solaris, AIX, HP-UX, and Linux.

So here is the solution as a ksh function:

```
is_modern_ksh() {
  if whence -a whence > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    return 0 #success -> true
  fi
  #Else the call to `whence` failed because `-a` is not supported
  return 1 #failure -> false
}
```

And here's how to use it:

```
if is_modern_ksh ; then
  echo "You're using a MODERN version of ksh. :)"
else
  echo "You're using an OLD version of ksh. :("
fi
```

Comment: Why don't you use `${.sh.version}`?

Comment: @cuonglm because I can't.  See the comments on [Gilles' answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199936/83381).

Comment: unfortunately the `whence` in Zsh has `-a`

Comment: @GregA.Woods, this function is specifically for ksh. The function definition would go in .kshrc and so would not even exist for other shells such as zsh.  zsh has its own built-in `whence` command which is in no way tied to ksh or the version thereof.  I don't even know why you'd care to check if ksh is an old version from within an instance of zsh, which is a completely different shell.

Comment: There is a problem with your assumptions:  Zsh is often installed with a link to `/bin/ksh`, e.g. on Debian Linux.  Now I don't use it there (and at the moment I can't change my login shell to check), so I don't know if it reads `.kshrc` or not, but I would suspect it does.

Comment: @Greg do you mean that "zsh" is set as a symbolic link to run ksh?  If so, then you're not running zsh at all.  And if that version of ksh supports `-a`, then that necessarily means that it's a modern version of `ksh`; and the `is_modern_ksh` function is just doing its job.

Comment: @Greg Or do you mean that zsh calls into ksh for some of its functionality?  If so, I doubt you even need this function.  My main reason for needing a function like this was the need to know when to work around a lack of specific functionality in old versions of ksh.  Is there a specific shortcoming of old ksh versions that is bleeding into zsh for you?  If so, I'd be surprised since the founding principle of zsh is that it combines the best of all other shells while discarding all of the shortcomings.

Comment: No, Zsh pretends to be Ksh, though until the most recent releases it did so rather poorly in some situations.

Comment: Does not work with mksh: `mksh: whence: -a: unknown option`. KSH_VERSION is: `@(#)MIRBSD KSH R54 2016/11/11` (on Debian 9 / stretch)

Comment: @MichaelBrux The whole point is for an error to be thrown for older versions, which the error redirection then consumes.  That's how this function identifies the ksh version as "old". Are you saying that the error redirection isn't working?

Comment: @Sildoreth: "mksh is a successor of pdksh" - means, from my understanding, it is modern. Your code returns "OLD version", what is an error, from my point of view. Reason for this error is: mksha whence builtin has no -a option. Is that more clear / understandable / correct?

Answer (score 10):

`KSH_VERSION` was not implemented in `ksh93` before version 93t. It will be set in `mksh`, `pdksh`, `lksh`. So for checking the version of `ksh`, we can try these steps:

- Checking `KSH_VERSION` to detect `mksh`, `pdksh`, `lksh`
- If first step fails, try a feature that's different between `ksh93` and `ksh88/86` ([Let David Korn show us](http://markmail.org/message/6xijgi35pqmjw37t#query:+page:1+mid:m7jkcvb6tm5ffktb+state:results)).

With these in mind, I will go with:

```
case "$KSH_VERSION" in
  (*MIRBSD*|*PD*|*LEGACY*) printf '%s\n' "$KSH_VERSION" ;;
  (*) [ -z "$ERRNO" ] && printf '%s\n' "${.sh.version}" || echo ksh88/86 ;;
esac
```

Comment: Why doesn't this check if `$KSH_VERSION` is non-blank first?  On my Ubuntu machine, this prints "ksh93", yet `KSH_VERSION` is set.

Comment: This would fail if some previously executed code (eg: .kshrc) tampered the KSH_VERSION variable with some random value.

Comment: @jlliagre: No, as it was run as a script, it don't read `.kshrc`.

Comment: If the `ENV` variable is set (and typically it is set to `~/.kshrc`), the script will definitely read the `.kshrc` file. Of course, it would be quite odd for a script to set a bogus KSH_VERSION but this is nevertheless possible, just like explicitly executing a script with a different interpreter than the one specified in its first line is a possible situation.

Comment: @jlliagre: Even you can change it, you will get segfault when you reference to `KSH_VERSION`. And in `mksh`, `pdksh`, `lksh`, `KSH_VERSION` is marked as readonly.

Comment: `pdksh` and derived shells are indeed protected by having the `KSH_VERSION` variable readonly but AT&T `ksh` ones are not. Releases older than `ksh93t` (2008) don't set it and accept it as a variable name with no restriction. Any script based on KSH_VERSION can easily be fooled if that variable has previously been exported or is set in a `.kshrc` file. `ksh93t` and newer still do not segfault if this variable is set by an initialization script. `ksh93t` to `ksh93u` only segfault it the variable is already set in their starting environment. Segfaulting was a bug that has been fixed in `ksh93v`.

Answer (score 8):

I think that `.sh.version` has existed ever since the first version of ATT ksh 93. It isn't available in pdksh or mksh. Since `${.sh.version}` is a syntax error in shells other than ksh93, wrap the test for it in a subshell and protect it behind `eval`.

```
_sh_version=$(eval 'echo "${.sh.version}"' 2>/dev/null) 2>/dev/null
case $_sh_version in
  '') echo "This isn't ATT ksh93";;
  …
esac
```

`KSH_VERSION` started out in the public domain ksh clone (pdksh), and was added to the actual Korn shell relatively recently, in 2008 with ksh93t.

Rather than test for a version number, you should test for the specific feature that's giving you grief. Most features can be tested for by trying some construct in a subshell and see if it triggers an error.

Comment: I don't see any difference when using a subshell.  It still treats `${.sh.version}` as a syntax error that cannot be reconciled.  The message I get is `bad substitution`.

Comment: @sil The point of using a subshell is to catch the error. Redirect errors to `/dev/null` and ignore the exit status.

Comment: I understand what you're saying.  What I'm saying is that the error doesn't redirect.  It *always* prints to the console.  I tried this in Solaris, AIX, and HP-UX; and ksh exhibits this behavior in all of them.

Comment: @Sildoreth Ah. I'd only tested on Linux, and I don't have any of these OSes to test now. Does `eval '_sh_version=$(echo "${.sh.version}")' 2>/dev/null` work any better?

Comment: That's a little better.  It works prefectly in Solaris and HP-UX.  For AIX, it works at the command line but curiously starts failing again if I try to place it in a shell function.

Comment: For future readers, the OSes I'm referencing are Solaris 5.10, HP-UX 11, and AIX 7.

Comment: Better as `command eval '_sh_version=${.sh.version}' 2> /dev/null` or `{ _sh_version=...; } 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Unfortunately NetBSD sh (though not dash-0.5.7-3 on linux) will outright stop reading the script when it sees `${.sh.version}` with the complaint `Syntax error: Bad substitution`.

Comment: @GregA.Woods Ouch. Can you try `_sh_version=$(echo "${.sh.version}"; true) 2>/dev/null` or `_sh_version=$(eval 'echo "${.sh.version}"') 2>/dev/null` ?

Comment: `eval` to the rescue again!  The redirection has to be moved into the command expansion though:  `_sh_version=$(eval 'echo "${.sh.version}"' 2>/dev/null)`   Thank you very much!

Comment: FYI, my `eval` version even works with ksh88e (which I just got to build and run on NetBSD/amd64, albeit with some gross hacks and minor fixes).  I.e. it "works" in the sense that it leaves `_sh_version` empty and does not write anything to standard error; since as you know that version and those before it didn't have any way other than an editor command to show their version identification.

Comment: Why the second `2> /dev/null`?

Answer (score 7):

For "real" `ksh` releases (i.e. AT&T based), I use this command:

```
strings /bin/ksh | grep Version | tail -2
```

Here are various output I get:

Original ksh:

```
@(#)Version M-11/16/88i
```

dtksh;

```
@(#)Version 12/28/93
Version not defined
```

Modern ksh93:

```
@(#)$Id: Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01 $
```

For `pdksh`/`msh` `ksh` clones and modern AT&T `ksh` versions too, here is something that works:

```
$ mksh -c 'echo $KSH_VERSION'
@(#)MIRBSD KSH R50 2015/04/19
```

---

Edit:

I overlooked you were asking about doing it from inside a script, not by knowing the path to the tested ksh binary.

Assuming you really want the version of `ksh` used, and not the features it supports, here is one way to do it using only the `strings` command that should work on at least on Linux and Solaris:

```
echo $(for i in $(find /proc/$$ ! -type d ! -name "pagemap" | 
  grep -v "/path/" | grep -v "/fd/" ) ; do
  strings $i | egrep "([V]ersion|[K]SH_VERSION).*[0-9]" | sort -u
done 2>/dev/null)
```

Note that this method is unreliable as `/proc` might not be mounted, and there are certainly other weaknesses. It is untested on other Unix OSes.

Comment: This won't be distinguish between `lksh` and `pdksh` in Debian Jessie.

Comment: @cuonglm I have no Jessie to test. Do you mean `lksh` and `pdksh` can't be sorted out from their `KSH_VERSION`?

Comment: No, I mean running `strings` on them. `KSH_VERSION` definitively can.

Comment: @cuonglm Sorry if I was unclear. When I wrote « for "real" `ksh` releases », I was explicitly excluding non AT&T ksh clones like `pdksh`, `mksh` and `lksh`.

Comment: Running `strings` on some ksh binary is a bad idea because you don't know if that's the one that's running your script. Maybe your script is being run by `/usr/local/bin/ksh` or `/home/bob/bin/ksh` or `/bin/sh` or `/usr/posix/bin/sh` or …

Comment: @Gilles what if this was performed on the value returned by `command -v $0`?

Comment: @Sildoreth How is `$0` useful here? It designates the script, not to the interpreter.

Comment: @Gilles Oh. I was thinking .kshrc.  But I see what you mean.

Comment: @cuonglm I updated my reply with a method that works with the `strings` command with `lksh` and `pdksh` too.

Comment: @jlliagre: If script was called with `ksh script` or `lksh script` or `pdksh script`, your solution failed.

Comment: @cuonglm Granted, indeed. One cannot reliably use the interpreter line, answer updated.

Comment: I haven't seen `strings` used in a while. It is a good program. Thanks for reminding me of it!

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

or

<kbd>ESC</kbd> , <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Have typically proven very reliable as far as interactively determining the version of KSH you're using, however scripting them has proven more difficult.

Comment: this was the only one that worked for an AIX ksh 88f version.

Comment: I got the 
<kbd>ESC</kbd> , <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> option to work, after I ran `set -o vi` to set the keybindings to be vi-like. Before that, or with +o vi or -o emacs, it simply would not show me. PD KSH v5.2.14 99/07/13.2 on openbsd 6.1

Answer (score 0):

I think the fundamental problem with using ${.sh.version} is that ksh88 just stops, with a non-zero exit code.

So my solution is to put the code that references ${.sh.version} in a sub-shell, then test to see if the sub-shell exits non-zero and have code in the sub-shell that will work on versions of the ksh where referencing ${.sh.version} does work. Wrapping it into a function that is then called by another function that reverses the return code, so that the final call is checking for true.

```
function is_oldksh
{
    (test -n ${.sh.version}) 2>/dev/null
}

function oldkshtest
{

    is_oldksh || return 0 && return 1
}

oldkshtest && echo "old ksh" || echo "new ksh"
```

I have run this on AIX and Oracle Enterprise Linux 5 & 6, with ksh88, ksh93 and pdksh.

Pete

Comment: modern AT&T Ksh still supplies `.sh.version` (indeed `KSH_VERSION` is effectively an alias for it).  Also some shells, e.g. NetBSD sh, simply stop reading after encountering `${.sh.version}` and no amount of redirection can keep them running the script.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work reasonably well for all the shells I've tested, including old ksh88e and a nearly complete range of common Ksh clones (though only one version of each), though I've not yet tested an actual original Bourne shell (and doing so may require adapting the `test` expression for older versions....

Addendum:

I've now also successfully tested this with Heirloom Bourne Shell, although with an external (and more modern) `test` program.

```
is_attksh()
{
    # ksh93
    _sh_version=$(eval 'echo "${.sh.version}"' 2>/dev/null)
    # pdksh only
    _opt_login=$(set -o | grep login)

    test -n "${_sh_version}" -o \( -z "${_opt_login}" -a -n "${_}" -a -n "${ERRNO}" -a -n "${FCEDIT}" -a -n "${PS3}" \)
}
is_attksh && echo "AT&T Ksh${_sh_version:+: }${_sh_version:- (probably ksh88 or ksh86)}" || echo "not real ksh"

is_zsh()
{
    test -n "${ZSH_VERSION}"
}
is_zsh && echo "Zsh: ${ZSH_VERSION}" || echo "not zsh"
```

Comment: Why would you want to run this function for shells that aren't ksh? If you're running a script in bash or zsh, then ksh never comes into play.  Furthermore, it's already been established via others' answers that `${.sh.version}` cannot be part of the solution because certain versions of ksh – the versions that the original post was concerned about – error fatally on that syntax.

Comment: As I said, the function I show has been tested with versions of ksh that give "fatal" errors, as well as versions of Ash that do the same.

Comment: Scripts I write are intended to be portable and to be run by any capable shell.  Also, as I said elsewhere, some folks won't necessarily know they're using Zsh as Ksh because when they type 'ksh' the Zsh binary will be invoked (with argv[0] as "ksh").

Comment: That does shed light on where you're coming from. However, that sounds like an unrealistic requirement.  Typically, when a Unix developer says "portable", they don't mean "this code will run in any *shell*", they mean "this will run on any *system*".  And if you need to execute a script that was written for another shell, that is perfectly legal; just start a non-interactive instance of the other shell in your script.

I bring this up because I want to promote good coding practices.  If this solution works for you, great.  But I would advise others to take a simpler approach.

Comment: I've been writing portable shell scripts that are intended to work with any Bourne (and later POSIX) *compatible* `/bin/sh` for the past 28 years.  :-)

Comment: Admittedly any efforts to drag backwards compatibility too far into the past are rather silly.  I've only compiled versions of ancient AT&T Ksh and Unix Sh to satisfy my own personal desire to better understand the history and evolution of some features and to refresh my memory of how things were (which usually surprises me, as things were often much "better" than I remember, though sometime they were also much worse).