# Test for array support by shell

Tags: shell-script, shell, array

Is there a concise way of testing for array support by the local Bourne-like shell at command line ?

This is always possible:

```
$ arr=(0 1 2 3);if [ "${arr[2]}" != 2 ];then echo "No array support";fi
```

or testing for `$SHELL` and shell version:

```
$ eval $(echo "$SHELL --version") | grep version
```

and then reading the man page, assuming I have access to it. (Even there, writing from `/bin/bash`, I am assuming that all Bourne-like shells admit the long option `--version`, when that breaks for ksh [for instance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199900/how-can-i-safely-get-the-version-of-ksh).)

I am looking for a simple test that could be unattended and incorporated in a *Usage* section at beginning of script or even before calling it.

Comment: I assume you want to limit to Bourne-like shells?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Yes, if you mean (not exhaustively) the core group made of : sh, csh, ksh, tcsh, bash, zsh and close friends. I don't know where yash positions itself in this constellation.

Comment: `csh` is not a bourne shell.   `tcsh` isn't one either (it's `csh` with some bugs fixed)

Comment: Note that `$SHELL` is the prefered shell of the user, like `$EDITOR` is his preferred text editor. It has little to do with  the currently running shell.

Comment: `eval`uating the output of `$SHELL --version` as shell code doesn't make sense.

Comment: What's the intended usage? Is that for code to be sourced by a user in his interactive shell?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I was not suggesting `eval $(echo "$SHELL --version") | grep version` should be implemented as shell code at all. This was just to emphasize my helplessness. And yes, the intended usage is sourcing code from an interactive shell in an environment where the  preferred shell may vary from user to user.

Comment: It strikes me as slightly odd that you're writing a script of an _unknown_ shell. If you're writing for `bash`, you _know_ there are arrays. Likewise in `ksh93`, `zsh`, and `yash`. As long as you know what shell you are writing for, you should have a fairly easy time testing the version of that shell to know if a recent enough release of it is installed for your script to function properly, or use feature test commands to see whether they are enabled in that shell. There should be no need for a polyglot shell script. It's like having to test whether an interpreter supports Perl hashes.

Comment: @Kusalananda: 3.5 yrs after the fact, I had no problem remembering the motivation of my post. When writing a script I often can't predict exactly on what platform it'll end up running. Arrays are handy but have different implementations on Bourne like shells (beyond POSIX as of today obviously). So automating whether to execute a script block or another, when arrays come into play, seemed like an acceptable hack. I've evolved on that point since. I now tend to stay away from arrays, which sometimes is difficult, as in Jeff Schaller's answer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508016.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you want to restrict to Bourne-like shells (many other shells like `csh`, `tcsh`, `rc`, `es` or `fish` support arrays but writing a script compatible at the same time to Bourne-like shells and those is tricky and generally pointless as they are interpreters for completely different and incompatible languages), note that there are significant differences between implementations.

The Bourne like shells that support arrays (in chronological order of when support was added) are:

- `ksh88` (the last evolution of the original ksh, the first one implementing arrays, ksh88 is still found as `ksh` on most traditional commercial Unices where it's also the basis for `sh`)

  - arrays are one-dimensional
  - Arrays are defined as `set -A array foo bar` or `set -A array -- "$var" ...` if you can't guarantee that `$var` won't start with a `-` or `+`.
  - Array indices start at `0`.
  - Individual array elements are assigned as `a[1]=value`.
  - arrays are sparse. That is `a[5]=foo` will work even if `a[0,1,2,3,4]` are not set and will leave them unset.
  - `${a[5]}` to access the element of indice 5 (not necessarily the 6th element if the array is sparse). The `5` there can be any arithmetic expression.
  - array size and subscript is limited (to 4096).
  - `${#a[@]}` is the number of assigned element in the array (not the greatest assigned indice).
  - there is no way to know the list of assigned subscripts (other than testing the 4096 elements individually with `[[ -n "${a[i]+set}" ]]`).
  - `$a` is the same as `${a[0]}`. That is arrays somehow extend scalar variables by giving them extra values.
- `pdksh` and derivatives (that's the basis for the `ksh` and sometimes `sh` of several BSDs and was the only opensource ksh implementation before ksh93 source was freed):

  Mostly like `ksh88` but note:

  - Some old implementations didn't support `set -A array -- foo bar`, (the `--` wasn't needed there).
  - `${#a[@]}` is one plus the indice of the greatest assigned indice. (`a[1000]=1; echo "${#a[@]}"` outputs 1001 even though the array has only one element.
  - in newer versions, array size is no longer limited (other than by the size of integers).
  - recent versions of `mksh` have a few extra operators inspired from `bash`, `ksh93` or `zsh` like assignments a la `a=(x y)`, `a+=(z)`, `${!a[@]}` to get the list of assigned indices.
- `zsh`. `zsh` arrays are generally better designed and take the best of `ksh` and `csh` arrays. As you can see from [the zsh 2.0 announcement in 1991](https://groups.google.com/forum/message/raw?msg=comp.sources.misc/NnkewmK-26s/dXy0FqhBBkwJ), the design was inspired from tcsh rather than ksh. They have some resemblance with `ksh` arrays but with significant differences:

  - indices start at 1, not 0 (except in `ksh` emulation), that's consistent with the Bourne array (the position parameters $@, which `zsh` also exposes as its $argv array) and `csh` arrays.
  - they are a separate type from normal/scalar variables. Operators apply differently to them and like you'd generally expect. `$a` is not the same as `${a[0]}` but expands to the non-empty elements of the array (`"${a[@]}"` for all the elements like in `ksh`).
  - they are normal arrays, not sparse arrays. `a[5]=1` works but assigns all the elements from 1 to 4 the empty string if they were not assigned. So `${#a[@]}` (same as `${#a}` which in ksh is the size of the element of indice 0) is the number of elements in the array **and** the greatest assigned indice.
  - associative arrays are supported.
  - a great numbers of operators to work with arrays is supported, too big to list here.
  - arrays defined as `a=(x y)`. `set -A a x y` also works for compatibility with `ksh`, but `set -A a -- x y` is not supported unless in ksh emulation (the `--` is not needed in zsh emulation).
- `ksh93`. (here describing latest versions). `ksh93`, a rewrite of `ksh` by the original authors, long considered *experimental* can now be found in more and more systems now that it has been released as FOSS. For instance, it's the `/bin/sh` (where it replaced the Bourne shell, `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`, the POSIX shell is still based on `ksh88`)  and `ksh` of `Solaris 11`. Its arrays extend and enhance ksh88's.

  - `a=(x y)` can be used to define an array, but since `a=(...)` is also used to define compound variables (`a=(foo=bar bar=baz)`), `a=()` is ambiguous and declares a compound variable, not an array.
  - arrays are multi-dimensional (`a=((0 1) (0 2))`) and array elements can also be compound variables (`a=((a b) (c=d d=f)); echo "${a[1].c}"`).
  - A `a=([2]=foo [5]=bar)` syntax can be used to define sparse arrays at once.
  - maximum array index raised to 4,194,303.
  - Not to the extent of `zsh`, but great number of operators supported as well to manipulate arrays.
  - `"${!a[@]}"` to retrieve the list of array indices.
  - associative arrays also supported as a separate type.
- `bash`. `bash` is the shell of the GNU project. It's used as `sh` on recent versions of OS/X and some GNU/Linux distributions. `bash` arrays mostly emulate `ksh88` ones with some features of `ksh93` and `zsh`.

  - `a=(x y)` supported. `set -A a x y` *not* supported. `a=()` creates an empty array (no compound variables in `bash`).
  - `"${!a[@]}"` for the list of indices.
  - `a=([foo]=bar)` syntax supported as well as a few others from `ksh93` and `zsh`.
  - recent `bash` versions also support associative arrays as a separate type.
- `yash`. It's a relatively recent, clean, multi-byte aware POSIX sh implementation. Not in wide use. Its arrays are another clean API similar to `zsh`

  - arrays are not sparse
  - Array indices start at 1
  - defined (and declared) with `a=(var value)`
  - elements inserted, deleted or modified with the `array` builtin
  - `array -s a 5 value` to modify the 5<sup>th</sup> element would fail if that element was not assigned beforehand.
  - the number of elements in the array is `${a[#]}`, `${#a[@]}` being the size of the elements as a list.
  - arrays are a separate type. You need `a=("$a")` to redefine a scalar variable as an array before you can add or modify elements.
  - `"$array"` expands to all the elements of the array as-is, which makes them much easier to use than in other shells (`cmd "$array"` to call `cmd` with the elements of the array as arguments compared to `cmd "${array[@]}"` in ksh/bash/zsh; `zsh`'s `cmd $array` is close but strips empty elements).
  - arrays are not supported when invoked as `sh`.

So, from that you can see that detecting for array support, which you could do with:

```
if (unset a; set -A a a; eval "a=(a b)"; eval '[ -n "${a[1]}" ]'
   ) > /dev/null 2>&1
then
  array_supported=true
else
  array_supported=false
fi
```

is not enough to be able to use those arrays. You'd need to define wrapper commands to assign arrays as a whole and individual elements, and make sure you don't attempt to create sparse arrays.

Like

```
unset a
array_elements() { eval "REPLY=\"\${#$1[@]}\""; }
if (set -A a -- a) 2> /dev/null; then
  set -A a -- a b
  case ${a[0]}${a[1]} in
    --) set_array() { eval "shift; set -A $1"' "$@"'; }
        set_array_element() { eval "$1[1+(\$2)]=\$3"; }
        first_indice=0;;
     a) set_array() { eval "shift; set -A $1"' -- "$@"'; }
        set_array_element() { eval "$1[1+(\$2)]=\$3"; }
        first_indice=1;;
   --a) set_array() { eval "shift; set -A $1"' "$@"'; }
        set_array_element() { eval "$1[\$2]=\$3"; }
        first_indice=0;;
    ab) set_array() { eval "shift; set -A $1"' -- "$@"'; }
        set_array_element() { eval "$1[\$2]=\$3"; }
        first_indice=0;;
  esac
elif (eval 'a[5]=x') 2> /dev/null; then
  set_array() { eval "shift; $1=("'"$@")'; }
  set_array_element() { eval "$1[\$2]=\$3"; }
  first_indice=0
elif (eval 'a=(x) && array -s a 1 y && [ "${a[1]}" = y ]') 2> /dev/null; then
  set_array() { eval "shift; $1=("'"$@")'; }
  set_array_element() {
    eval "
      $1=(\${$1+\"\${$1[@]}"'"})
      while [ "$(($2))" -ge  "${'"$1"'[#]}" ]; do
        array -i "$1" "$2" ""
      done'
    array -s -- "$1" "$((1+$2))" "$3"
   }
  array_elements() { eval "REPLY=\${$1[#]}"; }
  first_indice=1
else
  echo >&2 "Array not supported"
fi
```

And then you access array elements with `"${a[$first_indice+n]}"`, the whole list with `"${a[@]}"` and use the wrapper functions (`array_elements`, `set_array`, `set_array_element`) to get the number of elements of an array (in `$REPLY`), set the array as a whole or assign individual elements.

Probably not worth the effort. I'd use `perl` or limit to the Bourne/POSIX shell array: `"$@"`.

If the intent is to have some file to be sourced by the interactive shell of a user to define functions that internally use arrays, here are a few more notes that may be useful.

You can configure `zsh` arrays to be more like `ksh` arrays in local scopes (in functions or anonymous functions).

```
myfunction() {
  [ -z "$ZSH_VERSION" ] || setopt localoption ksharrays
  # use arrays of indice 0 in this function
}
```

You can also emulate `ksh` (improve compatibility with `ksh` for arrays and several other areas) with:

```
myfunction() {
  [ -z "$ZSH_VERSION" ] || emulate -L ksh
  # ksh code more likely to work here
}
```

With that in mind and you're willing to drop support for `yash` and `ksh88` and older versions of `pdksh` derivatives, and as long as you don't try to create sparse arrays, you should  be able to consistently use:

- `a[0]=foo`
- `a=(foo bar)` (but not `a=()`)
- `"${a[#]}"`, `"${a[@]}"`, `"${a[0]}"`

in those functions that have the `emulate -L ksh`, while the `zsh` user still using his/her arrays normally the zsh way.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `eval` to try the array syntax:

```
is_array_support() (
  eval 'a=(1)'
) >/dev/null 2>&1

if is_array_support; then
  echo support
else
  echo not
fi
```

Comment: `ksh88` supports arrays but not `a=()`. In `ksh93`, `a=()` declares a compound variable, not an array unless the variable has been declared as an array beforehand.

Comment: Also note that there are significant differences between array implementations. For instance, some have array indices starting at 0 (bash, ksh, zsh in ksh emulation), some starting at one (zsh, yash). Some are normal arrays/lists, some are sparse arrays (associative arrays with keys limited to positive integers like in ksh or bash).

Comment: In `yash`, you don't do `a[5]=1` but `array -s a 5 1`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: thanks for the precisions. In my case everything boils down to whether arrays (associative or not) are supported at all. Details about index-base can be easily worked out even in a script meant to run unattended.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: The compound variable in `ksh93` made me surprise, would you mind giving me part of documentation about it. I add `1` to the array to make it work.

Comment: @cuonglm, search for _compound_ in the man page. See for instance. `var=(a=1 b=2 c=(foo bar)); echo ${var.a} ${var.b[1]}`... You can do some object-oriented design with `typeset -T` that also adds support for functions in those compound variables.