# set -A command not running in Linux

Tags: shell, shell-script, ksh, aix

```
if [ $UNITS = day ]; then

   while ((OFFSET > 0)); do
      if (( OFFSET >= day )) ;then
         month=$((month - 1))
         if (( month == 0 )) ;then
            year=$((year - 1))
            month=12
         fi
         set -A days `cal $month $year`
         OFFSET=$((OFFSET - day))
         day=${days[$(( ${#days[*]}-1 ))]}
      else
         day=$((day - OFFSET))
         OFFSET=0
      fi
   done
```

The above code patch is running fine in AIX but when I am trying to run the same in Linux I am getting the below error:

```
set: -A: invalid option
set: usage: set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [arg ...]
```

Comment: you're trying to set an array? what shell are you using? `set -A` is even deprecated in `ksh` nowadays. looks like `bash` based on the `BHCP` stuff. do `days=($(cal $month $year))`

Comment: @mikeserv: Would you please linking me to the source indicate that `set -A` is deprecated.

Comment: @cuonglm - cant find it now, and maybe i had it wrong anyway, but i could swear ive read several times somewhere that setting vars with `set` was deprecated syntax because korn intends typeset to handle all of that.

Answer (score 1):

That's because in Linux, the default user shell is often `bash`, and the `/bin/sh` was often symlinked to `/bin/bash` (on Redhat base distro) or `/bin/dash` (on Debian and Ubuntu base distro).

Declaring array `set -A` is `ksh` syntax, first implemented in `ksh88`, and also supported in `ksh93`, `pdksh` and its derivatives, and `zsh`.

You can switch to other array syntax, which supported both by `ksh` and `bash`:

```
set -f # turn off globbing
days=( $(cal "$month" "$year") )
```

or using [Stéphane Chazelas's one here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238129/38906).