# Bash: minus one to the sub string split by separator

Tags: bash, shell-script, rename, mv

I would like to batch rename filenames turning
`A-B-C#2-D.wav` to `A-B-C#1-D.wav`. So for example:

```
A-B-C#2-D.wav
A-B-C#8-G.wav
A-B-C6-E.wav
```

becomes

```
A-B-C#1-D.wav
A-B-C#7-G.wav
A-B-C5-E.wav
```

So the number in the third substring should be decreased by one.
(`#` is the part of filenames instead of comment; both filenames with and without `#` are possible.)

Comment: Is the third example actually...C#6?

Comment: No, sorry for the misleading. It is what it is to highlight they can be both with and without `#`

Comment: Not a duplicate, but `vim` can do this relatively easy. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195503/vim-replace-n-with-n1

Comment: Please describe exactly the format of the file names. Is there always exactly `A-B-C` or should `A`, `B`, `C` stand for any character (except `-`) or for a string of variable length (without `-`)? Does the file name always contain exactly 3 `-`? Does the number always precede immediately the 3rd `-`? Do the numbers always consist of exactly 1 digit? If number `0` is possible, should it be replaced with `-1`? ...

Comment: If `#` occurs elsewhere in the filename, it should not be modified?

Answer (score 2):

With a bash-specific loop (for the regular-expression testing conditional `=~`):

```
for file in ?-?-*-?.wav
do
  [[ $file =~ ^([^[:digit:]]+)([[:digit:]]+)(-.\.wav)$ ]] &&
    echo mv -- "$file" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$((10#${BASH_REMATCH[2]} - 1))${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
done
```

This uses a wildcard to pick up the desired `wav` files; matching files will have one character (letter) between the dashes and before the `.wav` at the end. Each filename is run through the regular expression, which separates it into three pieces:

1. `^([^[:digit:]]+)` -- the leading portion; everything up to *but not including* the first digit
2. `([[:digit:]]+)` -- the digit(s)
3. `(-.\.wav)` -- the trailing portion

If the match succeeds, then we rename the file, using the leading portion, the digits minus one, and the trailing portion.

Remove the `echo` when the output looks correct.

Comment: Good catch; thank you Stéphane! I've tweaked the regex to be less greedy and also forced base-10 in the arithmetic.

Comment: well spotted again; I've simplified the regex to mirror yours and gobble up non-digits ahead of the digits

Comment: +1 Really nifty ! I permitted myself one small edit: when I first read your regex pattern, I just misinterpreted the bit [^[:digit:]]+ and in particular the caret in it which excludes the digit(s) from the match from the beginning of the string (=~ ^...) up to it. as a result I could not understand the fact you include the digits in the second part of the pattern matching [[:digit:]]+ and make good on it with the base-10 arithmetics on BASH_REMATCH[2]. Really nice. I'll try to write a POSIX compliant version and post it with no `[[ ]]` and no array...

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '(*[^0-9])(<1->)(*.wav)(#qn)' '$1$(($2-1))$3'
```

(remove the `-n` if satisfied)

The `(#qn)` is for the list to be numerically sorted so that `A-B-C#9-D.wav` be renamed *before* `A-B-C#10-D.wav` for instance.

However, if there were both a `A-B-C#9-D.wav` and `A-B-C#10-D.wav`, `zmv` would flag the fact that one file would be renamed to the name of an existing file and abort the command. You'd need to add the `-f` option to still force it.

Or with zsh (for the numeric glob order) and `perl`'s rename:

```
rename -n 's/\d+/$&-1/e' ./*[1-9]*.wav(#qn)
```

(same caveat and same `-f` option with some variants of `rename`).