# How to iterate over array indices in zsh?

Tags: shell-script, zsh, array

In bash we can iterate over index of an array like this

```
~$ for i in "${!test[@]}"; do echo $i; done
```

where test is an array, say,

```
~$ test=(a "b c d" e f)
```

so that the output looks like

```
0
1
2
3
```

However, when I do the same in zsh I get an error:

```
➜ ~ for i in "${!test[@]}"; do echo $i; done
zsh: event not found: test[@]
```

What is going on?

What is the proper way of iterating over indices in zsh?

Comment: Why do you expect the output to start at 0? `zsh` arrays start at 1.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`zsh` arrays are normal arrays like those of most other shells and languages, they are not like in ksh/bash associative arrays with keys limited to positive integers (aka sparse arrays). `zsh` has a separate variable type for associative arrays (with keys being arbitrary sequences of 0 or more bytes).

So the indices for normal arrays are always integers ranging from 1 to the size of the array (assuming ksh compatibility is not enabled in which case array indices start at 0 instead of 1).

So:

```
typeset -a array
array=(a 'b c' '')
for ((i = 1; i <= $#array; i++)) print -r -- $array[i]
```

Though generally, you would loop over the array members, not over their indices:

```
for i ("$array[@]") print -r -- $i
```

(the `"$array[@]"` syntax, as opposed to `$array`, preserves the empty elements).

Or:

```
print -rC1 -- "$array[@]"
```

to pass all the elements to a command.

Now, to loop over the keys of an *associative array*, the syntax is:

```
typeset -A hash
hash=(
  key1  value1
  key2  value2
  ''    empty
  empty ''
)
for key ("${(@k)hash}") printf 'key=%s value=%s\n' "$key" "$hash[$key]"
```

(with again `@` inside quotes used to preserve empty elements).

Though you can also pass both keys and values to commands with:

```
printf 'key=%s value=%s\n' "${(@kv)hash}"
```

For more information on the various array designs in Bourne-like shells, see [Test for array support by shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/238080)

Answer (score 5):

As said in this article [A User's Guide to the Z-Shell - Chapter 5: Substitutions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide05.html):

This is extended for other parameters in the following way:

```
% array=(one two three)
% print -l "${array[@]}"
one
two
three
```

and more generally for all forms of substitution using another flag, (@):

```
% print -l "${(@)array}"
one
two
three
```

So, maybe just try using second way?

Comment: Hi Anaoliy, I used the wrong example output for my question which was misleading. Terribly sorry about that! I've edited the question.

Comment: Note that forgetting the `--` to delimit options from arguments to `print` is very dangerous in zsh. That introduces command injection vulnerabilities as processing of some options can cause commands to be executed like with `array=('-va[$(reboot)1]')` here. You also forgot the `-r` option. To print the elements one per line, use `print -rC1 -- "$array[@]"` as shown in my answer. `print -l` prints an empty line when not passed any argument.

Answer (score 5):

And with curly brackets `{ }`:

```bsh
% test=(a "b c d" e f)                 
% for i in {1..$#test}; do echo $i; done
1
2
3
4
%
```